# Easiest way to monitor if Tor is running?

Tags: bash

I am trying to find the absolute easiest and simplest way to monitor whether or not the Tor process is running.

The idea I have in mind is incredibly simple and would be checked every minute via cron.

The reason behind this exercise is due to some hosts who allocate resources rather tight and thus killing (i.e OOM-killing) the Tor process, meaning I have to manually re-connect the disconnected server.

I'm actually just assuming the process is being killed due to resource exhaustion. It could be something else, as well. I will investigate this more in-depth at a later stage, but for now I just need a quick and dirty temporary 'solution' which restarts the process after it is discovered as having been stopped/killed.

So, now for my proposed 'fix':

```
#!/bin/bash
if /bin/ps aux  | grep /usr/bin/tor >/dev/null
  then
    echo "Tor is running. Exiting."
    exit 0
  else
    echo "Tor is not running. Reloading daemon(s)."
    service tor restart
    exit 1
fi
```

I named this something like "tor-monitor.sh" and created a crontab entry which checks every minute and that is it.

This *seems* to be working. But I am sure there has to be a better way of doing this. Do keep in mind that I'd like to have no bloat and not complicate matters, keep it simple.

Do any of you have a better solution? If you do, please post and I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The system's service manager (such as `systemd`) should already be doing this sort of health checking and automatic remediation.  If your system isn't using `systemd`, consider using a lightweight supervision system such as [`runit`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runit).